# using excel vba to change the value of a dropdown menu that after activate and populate a second dropdown menu

Tags: forms, vba, excel, internet-explorer

I am writin a macro excel to fill out a form in a web site.
My issue is that I can valorize the drop down menù (is a select command) but this should activate and populate a second drop down menù.. that does not appear

The code is

' this is the first select to choice the REGION

```
<select name="ctl00$cp$ddlRegion" id="ctl00_cp_ddlRegion">
<option value="">seleziona...</option>
<option value="13">Abruzzo</option> 
<option value="17">Basilicata</option>
<option value="18">Calabria</option>
<option value="15">Campania</option>
<option value="08">Emilia-Romagna</option>
<option value="06">Friuli-Venezia Giulia</option>
<option value="12">Lazio</option>
<option value="07">Liguria</option>
<option value="03">Lombardia</option>
</select>
```

'the second select, depending from the region above, valorize the CITY

```
<select name="ctl00$cp$ddlProvince" id="ctl00_cp_ddlProvince">
<option value="">seleziona...</option>
<option value="070">Campobasso</option>
<option value="094">Isernia</option>
</select>
```

---

MY CODE IS:

```
IE.document.ALL("ctl00$cp$ddlRegion").Value = "03" ' that is LOMBARDIA
```

but after this line the value it appear.. but the second select does not activate.

I have tried with

```
IE.document.ALL("ctl00$cp$ddlRegion").focus
IE.document.ALL("ctl00$cp$ddlRegion").click
IE.document.ALL("ctl00$cp$ddlRegion").fireEvent ("onchange")

IE.document.ALL("ctl00$cp$ddlProvince").focus
IE.document.ALL("ctl00$cp$ddlProvince").disabled = false
```

BUT NOTHING... does anybody knows why......
thank you in advance
Alex

Comment: Very difficult to suggest changes without a URL

Comment: you are right but this kind of form are inside private area of web site    ex. www.casa.it, but as I said inside the private area  - with log in

Comment: the point is the I can valorize the field in the web page - the select object. The valorization of this object should activate the next select, and even if the first select is valorized, this does not activate the second select

Comment: Is there any method to "track" or "debug" the behaviour of a web site with a client like chrome? so that when I click or valorize an item or a select I can see what is doing...? .. and trying to replicate it.... :-((

Comment: Best you can do is use the Developer Tools to view the source and other attributes of the element you're interested in.

Comment: Tim please help me :-)))) I have found this site where the issue is the same:  https://www2.subito.it/aif#insert

Comment: I try to insert automatically via vba an advertize for an apartment. FIrst thing valorize correctly the first field "Categoria" (category) that sould "appartamento". If this value would be valorize correctly the radiobutton would change in VENDITA and AFFITTO. But even if I use the code:    IE.document.ALL("category").Focus
IE.document.ALL("category").Value = 7 ' that is appartamento

Comment: the value "appartamento" it appears... but nothing changes after to the set of radiobutton below..... it means that with this kind of select is not enough to valorize the .value